# How to display two columns in mobile using bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap 5. I have to show 2 columns on my mobile but it's displaying the 1 column.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xxl-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <h2>Heading one</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xxl-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <h2>Heading Two</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xxl-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <h2>Heading Three</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xxl-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <h2>Heading Four</h2>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Below is the screenshot of the browser.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no more `col-xs` [since v4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options), so change to `col-6`

Note: Also you don't need to duplicate equal breakpoints. just use the first ones (because it is mobile-first)

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-6">
      <h2>Heading one</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-6">
      <h2>Heading Two</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-6">
      <h2>Heading Three</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-6">
      <h2>Heading Four</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I haven't understood the note point.

Comment: Yes, It's working. can I use like col-xxl-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6 ?

Comment: but I am using it for different screen sizes.

Comment: bootstrap is mobile first, meaning breakpoints will be starting from small to larger screens, so whenever you put `col-6` it will 2 columns until you want to change to 4 columns (for example) and then you decide where you want to start having 4 cols, imagine it is a medium breakpoint, so after you start using `col-md-3`, from that and up will alaways be 3 columns