# Strange behavior of Bootsrap cols on nested rows, between sm and xs breakpoints

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm coding a little website using Bootstrap 5.
I'm trying to make 6 elements show on two lines for breakpoints >= md , and on a single line for smaller breakpoints. It works for the sm breakpoint, but when I reduce to xs breakpoint, the 6 elements show on a vertical line o_O And I don't understand why...

The code above is simplified to contain only what it's needed to reproduce the problem, other elements (other rows...) of my code seems to be not responsible for my problem.

Thanks !

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2">
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-2">A</div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-2">B</div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-2">C</div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-2">D</div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-2">E</div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-2">F</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to set the `xs` breakpoint. Since you aren't defining what the width of the elements are, they will be block level elements at 100% width. Just change your `col-sm-2` to `col-xs-2` on your letter elements. You should also change the `col-sm-12` on the container to `col-xs-12`

Comment: @disinfor I tried so, but when I do this, the 6 elements show on a vertical line for both xs and sm breakpoints

Comment: Ah...I forgot, it's just `col-2` you don't need the breakpoint size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No breakpoint identifier is necessary. `col-2` will work.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-2">A</div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-2">B</div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-2">C</div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-2">D</div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-2">E</div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-2">F</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It was that simple xD Thanks a lot
It works...

Answer (score 2):

You just have to change col-sm-2 to col-2 it will work for you example below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-2">A</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-2">B</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-2">C</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-2">D</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-2">E</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-2">F</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

remember that Bootstrap starts breakpoints from small screens to larger screens, In this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66444960/how-to-display-two-columns-in-mobile-using-bootstrap-5), they talk about the behavior of the grid
Regards